# How to make Android App (.apk file size) size smaller?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been working on Eclipse IDE and even the smallest apk file (Hello World) takes about 2-3MB of size.

While an application like Greenify, being so advanced, is < 2MB.

I did find some answers related to this but they were very complicated to understand.

Comment: You might be included some `libraries` that leads to increase in apk size.

Comment: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Basic/Button) builds an APK that is ~23KB. So, no, "even the smallest apk file" does not take "about 2-3MB of size". Your project that you created may take that size, but we cannot really help you without knowing more about that project. For example, you may be using `appcompat-v7` for an action bar backport, which will add to the size, particularly for debug builds.

Comment: Try using SVG files for your graphics (a small 3rd party open source library is required).

Comment: it takes 800KB with appcompat-v7 library..  i removed it and now it takes <500KB but still there is a library present by default named appcompat-v4.. how can i remove it..  will it break my application??

Answer (score 0):

[Look into setting up ProGuard for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html). I don't have experience running ProGuard in Eclipse, but on Gradle builds if you have `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` set to true, it will reduce the APK size.